# Saving plots as variables in python like in R

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I work in R's `ggplot()` I can store my plots as `p<-ggplot()...` This makes it easier to add elements to the plot and look at them before they are saved. Is there a way to do this in python? For example, I would like to be able to add elements to the first figure, `fig`, after I plot the new z values.

What `ggplot` can do with R.

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=factor(am),y=mpg))+geom_boxplot()
p+xlab("Transmission Type")+ylab("Miles Per Gallon (mpg)")
p
```

What I would like to do in Python.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3] 
y = [2,4,1]
fig = plt.plot(x, y) 
z = x*2 
y = [2,4,1]
fig2 = plt.plot(z, y) 
fig.show() 
fig2.show()
```

Comment: Note that `plt.plot` does not return a figure. You should be using `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, i.e. the object-oriented interface, see [this](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).

Comment: I kinda see how that solves my question, but at the same time you are still adding something to a plot. I would like something that is callable in case I do not like the ax2 for instance.

Comment: I would suggest providing a concrete ggplot example of what you're trying to achieve in matplotlib.

Comment: Added the concrete example.

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck, because your ggplot example doesn't match your Python one at all.

Comment: It  is just a concept. Add a new aspect to the plot. Doesn't have to be the exact same thing.

Comment: So is the key point that you can do `p+xlab("Transmission Type")+ylab("Miles Per Gallon (mpg)")` to get a "preview" of what it would look like without actually modifying `p`?

Comment: _"So we can modify the axes, but what if we want to remove elements added like replace ax2.plot(z,y) with ax2.plot(x,y)?"_ <- In matplotlib, I think the only way would be to clear it with `ax2.cla()` and re-plot: `ax2.plot(z, y); ax2.cla(); ax2.plot(x, y)`. The matplotlib operations occur in place, so I don't think that aspect of ggplot can be replicated here.